When i try to compile code by running npm run dev i am receiving error 1 ERROR in child compilations
Receiving below error when trying to run "npm run dev" for compiling
1 WARNING in child compilations(Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
ERROR in ./scss/libraries/main.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Invalid CSS after "}": expected "}", was ""
        on line 353 of scss/regions/_footer.scss
        from line 10 of scss/libraries/main.scss
>> }
   ^

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

maybe check ur sass file?

Thank you but i am getting various other warnings as mentioned in my comment. The compilation is not working.

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
WARNING in webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
1 WARNING in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)

Those warnings will not prevent you from viewing a compilation, they are just indicating your bundle size is perhaps too large. The error in your SASS file will prevent you from viewing the compilation though, because the browser can't render from incorrect syntax.

most likely its your Sass file syntax, try looking at it with good linting extensions built, it may hint you where youre having a problem.
